# Moving two circles together

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to move the circles using func1() and func2() by also using timers.But they are not moving at all. So, how to get the 'x' and 'x1' values from the two functions to paintComponent. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TC extends JPanel
{
    static Timer t1;
    static Timer t2;
    static Timer t3;
    static TimerTask tt1;
    static TimerTask tt2;
    static int x = 0 ,x1 = 500;
    static int y = 100,i = 0,j = 0;
    static Graphics g1;
    static int var = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    TC T = new TC();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("TC");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JFrame ff = new JFrame("2nd Frame");
    ff.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TextField tf1 ,tf2;
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    tf1 = new TextField();
    tf2 = new TextField();  
    tf1.setBounds(50,50, 200, 20);
    tf2.setBounds(50,100, 200, 20);
    f.add(tf1);
    f.add(tf2);
    TC.func1(f,tf1);
    TC.func2(f,tf2);
    ff.add(T);
    ff.setSize(1000, 700);
    ff.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(1000,700);
    f.setVisible(true);   
}

static void func1(JFrame f,TextField tf1)
{
    //int delay = 100;
    TC T = new TC();
    t1 = new Timer();      
    tt1 = new TimerTask() 
    {
    @Override
    public void run() 
        {              
                    x += 1;
                    y = 100;
                    System.out.println(x);
                    System.out.println(y);
                    tf1.setText(Integer.toString(x));
            if(x1 == x)
            {
                t1.cancel();
                tt1.cancel();
            }             
        };

    };
    t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt1,0,50);      
}

static void func2(JFrame f,TextField tf2)
{
    t2 = new Timer();      
    tt2 = new TimerTask() 
    {
    @Override
    public void run() 
        {              
            x1 -= 1;
            y = 100;
            System.out.println(x1);
            System.out.println(y);
            tf2.setText(Integer.toString(x1);
            if(x1 == x)
            {
                t2.cancel();
                tt2.cancel();
            }
        }
    };
    t2.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt2,0,50);
}

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
            g1 = g; 
            g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
            g.fillOval(x1, y, 10, 10);
    }            
}
```

Comment: My intension was same for both the questions but I am not getting the accurate results from both the codes. Their approaches are entirely different.

Comment: both the questions are asked by me only.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you must repaint the circle each time that you move them.

Comment: repaint() is not working.